# Removing a Node from a Doubly Linked List in C

Tags: c, logic, doubly-linked-list

As a whole my program is for inserting and deleting nodes in a sorted doubly linked list. Insertion works and deleting the first node from the linked list works fine, except deleting the last node. Also, deleting nodes in the middle and end don't work. If I try to delete the last node, I am led back to main(); If I try deleting a node in the middle, the program crashes. Your help is appreciated!

```
void remove(int n){
    struct node* help = head;
    if(head->data == n){
        if (head->next)
            help->next->prev = NULL;
        head = help->next;
    } else{
        while(help){
            if(help->data == n){
                if(help->next)
                    help->next->prev = help->prev;
                help->prev->next = help->next;
            } else help = help->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Either run your program in a debugger and it will stop when it crashes, and you can then walk the call stack to your code. Or step through the code line by line to see what it does.

Comment: Oh and by the way, you might want to stop looping once you find the node you want to remove. And probably `free` that node as well.

Answer (score 1):

Either you break your while loop or update the `help` pointer to next item when `if(help->data ==n` is true.

Something like

```
    //your code
    ...
    while(help){
        if(help->data == n){
            if(help->next)
                help->next->prev = help->prev;
            help->prev->next = help->next;
            //if you don't want to remove all nodes that have data 'n'
            break;
        } 
        //if you want to remove all nodes that have data 'n' remove else. 
        //but keep help = help->next
        else 
           help = help->next;

    ...
     //your code
```

Comment: works in general, but I'm not able to delete the second node in the list!