# initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] while deleting a node in Binary tree

Tags: c

I am trying to delete a node from binary tree. My logic for the first and second case (when left or right =NULL works fine) but i have problem in third case when i try to delete a node that contains  two subtree(left and right as well),What i try to do is:

If the node value(is represented as "freq" in my code) is equal to the element to be deleted (represented as delete_val in my code, which is taken at terminal by user for an already existing tree).Then i go to the right most leaf of the left node and make it as successor and then replace it with the node that contains the value to be deleted.

My code to do so is (which produces error, I have mentioned the line containing error in my code):

```
    delete_tree_node(int delete_val, node  **root)    
    {   
        node*temp1;    
        temp1=(*root);          
       if(delete_val==(temp1)->freq)    
       {    
          if(temp1->left==NULL)    
           {    
               temp1=temp1->left;     
           }    
          else if(temp1->right==NULL)
           {    
               temp1=temp1->right;    
           }    
          else    
           {     
 Line:73    node **successor= get_successor(&temp1->left);    
            temp1->freq=(*successor)->freq;    
            delete_tree_node(temp1->freq,successor);     
           }    
       }      
       else if(delete_val<temp1->freq)    
       {      
            delete_tree_node(delete_val,&temp1->left);    
       }    
       else if(delete_val>temp1->freq)    
       {        
             delete_tree_node(delete_val,&temp1->right);    
       }
       (*root)=temp1;     
    }
```

where as the function get_successor() is :

```
Line:89     node**get_successor(node**suc)    
            {   
              node  *temp;    
              temp=*suc;     
              while(temp->right!=NULL)    
               {    
                 temp=temp->right;    
               }    
Line:97       return (temp);    
            }
```

And call to delete_tree_node() is

```
delete_tree_node(delete_val,&head);
```

The errors are as follows:

```
gcc cc.c -o cc    
cc.c: In function ‘delete_tree_node’:    
cc.c:73:26: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]    
cc.c: At top level:     
cc.c:89:8: error: conflicting types for ‘get_successor’    
cc.c:73:26: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘get_successor’ was here    
cc.c: In function ‘get_successor’:    
cc.c:98:4: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

Could some one please help me in removing these errors and warning in order to delete the desired node from user ? Piece of code would be a big help to make as reference.

Edit: I had not declared the function that's why it was giving the errors moreover i done `node*get_successor(node*suc)` removed one pointer and it worked fine on several samples i had tried except the one when i tried to do:
Total number of nodes=4
it just create duplicate in case if i take input like this (size =4) and nodes are: `1,12,14,55` and i am trying to delete "12" it deletes "12" but makes but makes a duplicate of "1" like`"1 1 14 55`". Do you know the reason for it ?In other cases it works fine(dont leave duplicate, this i was trying randomly and i found this problem)

My edited code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <malloc.h>     
#include <string.h>        
struct node     
{     
    int freq;    
    struct node * left, * right;    
};    
typedef struct node node;    
node* get_successor(node*suc);    

void insert_first_node(int data, node * * Node)     
{    
    node * temp1 = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));    
    temp1 -> freq = data;    
    temp1 -> left = NULL;    
    temp1 -> right = NULL;      
    *Node = temp1;    
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void insert_beginning(int data, node * * Node)     
{    
     node *root;    
     root = * Node;    
    if (root == NULL)     
    {    
        insert_first_node(data,Node);    
        return;    
    }    
    if (data <= root -> freq)     
    {     
       insert_beginning(data,&root->left);    
    } else     
    {    
       insert_beginning(data,&root->right);    
    }     
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

print_tree(node*Node)    
{    
 node * temp;     
 temp=Node;    
  if(temp!=NULL)    
  {    
    print_tree(temp->left);    
    printf(" %d  ",temp->freq);    
   print_tree(temp->right);    
   }    
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

delete_tree_node(int delete_val, node  **root)    
{    
    node*temp1;    
     temp1=(*root);     
    printf("check1\n");    
   if(delete_val==(temp1)->freq)    
   {    
        printf("check2\n");     
      if(temp1->left==NULL)    
       {    
           temp1=temp1->right;     
       }

     else if(temp1->right==NULL)    
      {    
          temp1=temp1->left;    
      }    
      else    
       {    
            node *successor= get_successor(temp1->left);    
        temp1->freq=(successor)->freq;    
           delete_tree_node(temp1->freq,&successor);     
        }    
   }   
   else if(delete_val<temp1->freq)    
   {     
        delete_tree_node(delete_val,&temp1->left);    
    }    
    else if(delete_val>temp1->freq)    
   {        
         delete_tree_node(delete_val,&temp1->right);    
   }    
   (*root)=temp1;     
}
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

node* get_successor(node*suc)    
{    
   node  *temp;    
   temp=suc;     
   while(temp->right!=NULL)    
   {    
     temp=temp->right;    
   }    
   return (temp);    
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

main()     
{    
    int i, size, data,delete_val;    
    node * head;    
    head = NULL;    
    printf("How many  nodes are to be inserted ?\n");    
     scanf("%d", & size);    
    for (i = 1; i <= size; i++)    
    {    
        printf("enter the nodes \n");    
        scanf("%d", & data);    
         insert_beginning(data, & head);
    }    
         print_tree(head);    
         printf("\n");     
         printf("enter the node to be delted from the tree constructed before? \n");

             scanf("%d", & delete_val);    
         delete_tree_node(delete_val, & head);     
         print_tree(head);    
             printf("\n");    
}
```

Edit: At last i got the reason for this wrong output of this duplicate the reason is in function `delete_tree_node(temp1->freq,&successor);`  i must do `delete_tree_node(successor->freq,&successor);`.

Comment: Return `node*` from `get_successor` not `node**`.

Comment: @tesseract i have made the changes you asked me to do and it runs error free but there is one problem that it makes duplicate of the deleted element. I which part of my code should i free the node so as to avoid the duplicate ?

Comment: sorry for taking it down, my changes require you to change the type of successor to `node *`, you may be using successor as `node **` in the rest of your code so it might cause problems unless you made the necessary changes.

Comment: @tesseract I made the changes you asked to do. Could you please write a piece of code mentioning the changes you asking to do ? I still don't understand but i like your answer

Comment: I think you were right before i need to keep node* not node**. Am i right because it works fine(without any error)except it just create duplicate in case if i take input like this (size =4) and nodes are: 1,12,14,55 and i am trying to delete "12" it deletes "12" but makes but makes a duplicate of "1" like"1 1 14 55". Do you know the reason for it ?In other cases it works fine(dont leave duplicate, this i was trying randomly and i found this problem).

Comment: @user234839 yes,thats why I was worried since you could be using node** in the rest of your code. your best option is to use gdb debugger and see why its printing twice. let me see what I can find. in all your function you dont need to pass node** all you need is node *

Comment: `print_tree(node*Node)` should be `void print_tree(node*Node)`, same for `delete_tree_node()`. And it shall be `int main(void)` at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node **successor= get_successor(&temp1->left) 

to

node *successor = get_successort(temp1->left);
```

there is no point in passing the address of temp1->left. you want to pass the value of      temp1->left not its address. if you pass the address and then do.

```
          node  *temp;    
          temp=*suc;  //this is unnecessary
```

You could Have achieved the same result by just passing the value of temp1->left. and assigning it to `node *temp = suc`

change the function to

```
 node *get_successor(node *suc)    
        {   
          node  *temp;    
          temp= suc; //no point in passing address of temp1    
          while(temp->right!=NULL)    
           {    
             temp=temp->right;    
           }    
Line:97       return (temp);    
        }
```

I deleted my comment because of these parts below, you have to change the type of successor to `node *` and now you have to adjust the rest of the code to match the type of successor

make these changes

```
       node *successor= get_successor(&temp1->left);    
        temp1->freq=(successor)->freq;    
        delete_tree_node(temp1->freq,successor);     
       }
```

Also change this part

```
delete_tree_node(int delete_val, node  *root)    
{   
    node*temp1;    
    temp1=(root);
```

regarding the double printing, I am not sure unless I see more code, But using gdb debugger this should be a very easy problem to solve.

Also your function return types were not specified. `void print_tree(node*Node)` `int main()` and `return 0` from main

Comment: thanks for the edited code, I also have added my edited code at the last of my asked question. Could you please go through that once ?

Comment: tesseract Yes i got why it it do so,instead of delete_tree_node(temp1->freq,&successor); i should do delete_tree_node(successor->freq,&successor); delete_tree_node function

Comment: nice work passing the `&sucessor` without needing to change the rest of your `delete_tree_node` function, thats why I was worried you can ignore my changes to `delete_tree_node` but should take note of them in the future its more elegant and readable, I ran your code, it ran fine for me I don't get the repeated 1,

Comment: But one thing i still don't understand where i have deleted the node?I just assign the freq of right most child of left subtree(in case if the root contains left and right subtree) but inever used free()/delete() to delete that node. I was not able to understand. could you please explain a bit in detail ?

Comment: http://cs-people.bu.edu/jalon/cs113-01/dlistlab/dlist.html, you should read up on doubly linked lists, check this aswell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509733/removing-a-node-from-a-doubly-linked-list-in-c

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure to declare the `get_successor` function above the `delete_tree_node` function, or else the C compiler assumes that the `get_successor` function returns an `int` when it is called from the `delete_tree_node` function.

You can either forward declare it:

```
node**get_successor(node**suc);

void delete_tree_node(int delete_val, node  **root) 
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

or define `get_successor` above `delete_tree_node`.

Comment: THANKS? i think you are right why compiler read it as integer, could you please explain a bit more (in terms of algo or piece of code)?

Answer (score 2):

```
cc.c:73:26: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]    
cc.c: At top level:     
cc.c:89:8: error: conflicting types for ‘get_successor’    
cc.c:73:26: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘get_successor’ was here    
cc.c: In function ‘get_successor’:
```

Theses errors/warnings is one thing, you didn't declare the function `get_successor` before calling it. So compile uses implicit declaration which returns `int`. The solution is to put the declaration before calling it.

```
cc.c:98:4: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

This warning is because in the function `get_successor`, the return type is `node**`, while the return value `temp` is of type `node *`.

Answer (score 2):

The code is your missing proper prototype for that function get_successor(). 2 possible solution is

1. define the function before the call
2. declare a prototype matching the definition if the function

And for the warning your returning `node*` but collecting it in `node**`

Answer (score 2):

In C, function prototypes are optional. When you call a function that was not declared before the call, the compiler assumes a `int` return value, and any number of arguments.

So when you don't define (or at least declare) `get_successor` before `delete_tree_node`, the compiler thinks there is a function like

```
int get_successor();
```

In line 73, you then call this function and convert the implied `int` return value to a `node **`, therefore the warning.

Later in line 83, the compiler sees the actual definition of `get_successor`, and that it returns a `node**`, not as assumed an `int`. Therefore the error.